# FortiGate Making Ports Appear Open

Tags: networking, port, nmap, fortigate

Recently we were doing some port scanning on some machines located in AWS to see what came up. This is in preparation for a launch of our new product in a couple of months. While doing this we got, what we considered to be, some weird results.

Performing the scan off of our corporate network we got the expected results for ports 80,443 and 3389 to be open. Though when we performed the scan on our corporate network we get some differing results. In addition to the three previously mentioned ports being open, ports 53 and 8008 were also coming back as open. Port 53 is what caught our attention at first as this machine is not used for DNS and the open ports are controlled at various layers in our infrastructure but notably security groups within AWS. We did a telnet to this instance/machine for ports 53/8008 but as expected a connection couldn't be made as the ports were closed.

In my experience NMap has been a pretty accurate tool for scanning. Digging into this deeper I found that ports 53/8008 are used by Fortigate devices for SDNS and Policy Override Authentication respectively. We are using Fortigate devices at our corporate offices. Therefore I'm wondering if the devices could be doing something that makes these ports appear open when we perform a scan from our corporate network.

Would anybody have any insight on this?

Comment: so just about any system is going to make DNS  queries. its not restricted to DNS servers or whatever. you don't mention protocols. is this TCP/53 or UDP? note that a port can't be open unless an application is using it.

Comment: I understand that any system is going to make queries. Port 53 is only open for inbound queries though. TCP/UDP shouldn't matter much in this situation. I'm also aware of when/why/how ports are opened. Please read my post in more detail. You'll see that I'm getting mixed results for a port scanner based on the environment from which the scan is being initiated. Therefore what I'm trying to figure out is whether our Fortigate is redirecting, modifying or doing something else to a request to make those ports appear open even though they aren't.